# Lists of list exercsie in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have this exercise:

> Write a deterministic Prolog program `test( +List, ?Integer )` that succeeds
> if and only if `Integer` is the number of ways two different elements in `List`
> can be selected such that the first has exactly one element more than the
> second.
>
> Sample query:
>
> ```
> ?- test( [ [], [0], [0,0], [0,1], [1,0] ], N ).
> N = 5
> ```

But i cannot figure out how i would do this. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, while completely removing any thought about performance:

Subgoal:

1. Select a first element (which is a list) using `member/2`; AND
2. Select a second element (which is a list) using `member/2`; AND
3. Compute the length of the first selected element/list using `length/2`; AND
4. Compute the length of the second selected element/list using `length/2`; AND
5. Make sure that the two lengths fit your length constraint using `</2`

   - Which will fail if this is not the case, backtracking back up this list
   - But if it suceeds, this goal succeeds.

Collect all the solutions of the subgoal using [`bagof/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3)

Comment: how do i select an element using memeber?

Comment: @fewfrg Check out the manual: [`member/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2) and try it on the command line or in [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/). There is no other way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog can be... difficult to wrap your head around when you are starting out.

First, try writing a predicate that will, on backtracking, return the entire *cartesian join* of the list against itself, something like this:

```
test( List, result( A, B ) ) :-
  member( A, List ),
  member( B, List )
  .
```

Running that with the test data: `test( [ [], [0], [0,0], [0,1], [1,0] ], R ).` will successively return 25 results (the sample list has 5 items in it, so 5 × 5 gives us 25 results, right?):

```
R = result( []    , []     )
R = result( []    , [0]    )
R = result( []    , [0, 0] )
R = result( []    , [0, 1] )
R = result( []    , [1, 0] )
R = result( [0]   , []     )
R = result( [0]   , [0]    )
R = result( [0]   , [0, 0] )
R = result( [0]   , [0, 1] )
R = result( [0]   , [1, 0] )
R = result( [0, 0], []     )
R = result( [0, 0], [0]    )
R = result( [0, 0], [0, 0] )
R = result( [0, 0], [0, 1] )
R = result( [0, 0], [1, 0] )
R = result( [0, 1], []     )
R = result( [0, 1], [0]    )
R = result( [0, 1], [0, 0] )
R = result( [0, 1], [0, 1] )
R = result( [0, 1], [1, 0] )
R = result( [1, 0], []     )
R = result( [1, 0], [0]    )
R = result( [1, 0], [0, 0] )
R = result( [1, 0], [0, 1] )
R = result( [1, 0], [1, 0] )
```

Once you have that, it's easy to compute the difference in length between the 2 sublists:

```
test( List, result( A, B ) ) :-
  member( A, List ),
  member( B, List ),
  length( A, L1   ),
  length( B, L2   ),
  Delta is L1 - L2
  .
```

And even easier to filter on that:

```
test( List, result( A, B ) ) :-
  member( A, List ),
  member( B, List ),
  length( A, L1   ),
  length( B, L2   ),
  Delta is L1 - L2,
  Delta = 1
  .
```